# Insert arrays to swift dictionary by alphabetically ordered keys

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have `swift` `struct` like below

```
Dog(
   'breed': 'Affenpoo',
   'age': '1'
)
```

and I want to insert this `Dog` `struct` to `swift` `dictionary` myDict that holds key as single letter that contains first latter of the `breed` and array of the `Dog`s as value.

```
var myDict = [String:[Dog]]
```

I have list of dogs from server fetch, and from for loop how can i insert to myDict with key as first latter of `breed`.

data from server

```
Dog(
    breed :"Boxer",
    age: 3
),
Dog(
    breed : "Affenpoo",
    age: 1
),
Dog(
    breed :"Affenpug",
    age: 1),
Dog(
    breed :"Affenshire",
    age: 2),
Dog(
    breed :"Bagle Hound",
    age: 2
),
Dog(
    breed :"Affenwich",
    age: 2
),
Dog(
    breed :"Afghan Collie",
    age: 2
),
Dog(
    breed :"Afghan Hound",
    age: 3
)




for dog in dogs {
   //here i have to insert dogs to myDict, and key as first letter of the dog.breed

}
```

At the end i want myDict to hold data like below.

```
  ["A":
    [Dog( breed : "Affenpoo", age: 1),
     Dog( breed :"Affenpug", age: 1),
     Dog( breed :"Affenshire", age: 2),
     Dog( breed :"Affenwich", age: 2),
     Dog( breed :"Afghan Collie", age: 2),
     Dog( breed :"Afghan Hound", age: 3)],
 "B":
    [Dog( breed :"Bagle Hound", age: 2),
     Dog( breed :"Boxer", age: 3)]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the prefix, if the key exists, append the item, if not create the key

```
for dog in dogs {
  let prefix = dog.breed.substringToIndex(dog.breed.startIndex.successor())
  if myDict.keys.contains(prefix) {
    myDict[prefix]!.append(dog)
  } else {
    myDict[prefix] = [dog]
  }
}
```

If you need the keys in alphabetical order use an extra array

```
var keys = [String]()

for dog in dogs {
  let prefix = String(dog.breed[dog.breed.startIndex])
  if keys.contains(prefix) {
    myDict[prefix]!.append(dog)
  } else {
    myDict[prefix] = [dog]
    keys.append(prefix)
  }
}
keys.sortInPlace(<)
```

Comment: Tanks,  this is perfect. And one more help now its shuffled order, is their anyway to make this dictionary items order by key?

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered by definition. To display the data in a table view use an extra array containing the sorted keys

Answer (score 2):

### The Dog struct

First of all update the `Dog` struct like this

```
struct Dog {
    let breed: String
    let age: Int

    init?(breed: String, age:Int) {
        guard breed.isEmpty == false else { return nil }
        self.breed = breed
        self.age = age
    }

    var firstChar: Character {
        return breed.characters.first!
        // this is safe because empty values for breed are not alloved by the initializer
    }
}
```

### List of Dog(s)

Now given the following list of Dogs

```
let dogs = [
    Dog(breed: "Boxer", age: 3),
    Dog(breed: "Affenpoo", age: 1),
    Dog(breed: "Affenpug", age: 1),
    Dog(breed: "Affenshire", age: 2),
    Dog(breed: "Bagle Hound", age: 2),
    Dog(breed: "Affenwich", age: 2 ),
    Dog(breed: "Afghan Collie", age: 2),
    Dog(breed: "Afghan Hound", age: 3)
].flatMap { $0 }
```

you can group the values into a dict

```
let dict = dogs.reduce([Character:[Dog]]()) { (var dict, dog) -> [Character:[Dog]] in
    if var list = dict[dog.firstChar] {
        list.append(dog)
        dict[dog.firstChar] = list
    } else {
        dict[dog.firstChar] = [dog]
    }
    return dict
}
```

### Ordered print

Finally you can get a sorted list of the keys in order to get an ordered print

```
dict.keys.sort().forEach { print("\($0): \(dict[$0]!)", terminator: "\n") }
```

Output:

```
A: [Dog(breed: "Affenpoo", age: 1), Dog(breed: "Affenpug", age: 1), Dog(breed: "Affenshire", age: 2), Dog(breed: "Affenwich", age: 2), Dog(breed: "Afghan Collie", age: 2), Dog(breed: "Afghan Hound", age: 3)]
B: [Dog(breed: "Boxer", age: 3), Dog(breed: "Bagle Hound", age: 2)]
```

Comment: A dog breed named with an empty string is quite hypothetical ;-)

Comment: @vadian: yes you are right :D. I thought about that and finally I decided to allow the empty `String` as a valid value but I agree that is questionable.

Comment: Actually that's is a good example for an `assertion` line instead of the failable initializer. Since the data come from a server, you would see on the first run if there is an empty string which is most unlikely.

Comment: @vadian: But after that, when the app is in production and the assert is removed, the server would have the "power" to make the app crash just by sending an empty `String`. I usually like being paranoid about data I do not generate.